# coordinate planes, why only 2 arrows

Tags: tkz-euclide

Found this coordinate plane in the forum, I really like it. I would like 4 arrows, 2 on each axis, pointing in all 4 directions instead of 2. Not sure why arrows only point right and up. I have seen this in MANY Cartesian planes.

TIA

[image]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
       \tkzGrid
       \tkzAxeXY
\draw[ thick,latex-latex] (-1,4) -- (4,-6) node[anchor=south west] {$a$}; % two points for drawing 2x+y=2
\tkzText[above](0,6.75){Desired Output}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Code for `pgfplots` coordinate plane

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  axis line style={Stealth-Stealth, very thick},
  xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  title={},
  grid=major,
  grid style={thick,black!50}]
\addplot [Latex-Latex,domain=-5:3,samples=2] {x*2/3} node[right]{$a$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You have two arrows there. One of them points left and up; the other one points right and down. Why then do you claim that arrows only point right and up?

Comment: Thanks. I resubmitted the image. Looking to get an arrow at the left edge of the x axis and the bottom of the y axis.

Comment: Highly recommend that you not use `tikz` for graphing and instead use `pgfplots` (which is built on top of `tikz`.

Comment: What does "I have seen this in MANY planes" mean? -e.g. the astral plane?

Comment: Cartesian planes

Comment: @Peter Grill - I have explored pgfplots. I will show code and pic above. Not sure how to fix font size for the numbers

Comment: See [tikz arrows - How to draw this vector diagram in latex? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353613/how-to-draw-this-vector-diagram-in-latex) for an example. Or the answers right below the post you copy the image from [diagrams - Coordinate system in LaTeX with TikZ - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155181/coordinate-system-in-latex-with-tikz) (you should link to the source when you copy.)

Comment: @PeterGrill I agree with you. `pgfplots` is the tool for graphing. `tkz-euclide` is for euclidean geometry.

Comment: For what is worth, plots usually only use two arrows rather than four because the arrows are not meant to indicate that the axes go on indefinitely, but to show the direction in which the coordinate increases (which in rare cases is the opposite of the usual one).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you change the distance specification

```
xtick distance=2,
ytick distance=2,
```

and to change the font of the tick labels you can use:

```
xticklabel style={font=\small},
yticklabel style={font=\small},
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  axis line style={Stealth-Stealth, thick},
  xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-10,ymax=10,
  xtick distance=2,
  ytick distance=2,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  xticklabel style={font=\small},
  yticklabel style={font=\small},
  title={},
  grid=major,
  grid style={thin,black!50}]
\addplot [Latex-Latex, red, thick, domain=-10:10,samples=2] {x*2/3} node[above left]{$a$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6,xmin=-6,ymin=-6]
   \tkzGrid
   \tikzset{xaxe style/.style    =   {>  =   latex,  <->}
   }  
   \tikzset{yaxe style/.style    =   {>          =   latex, < ->}
   }
   \tkzAxeXY
   \tkzDefPoints{-1/4/A,4/-6/B}
   \tkzDrawSegment[red,latex-latex](A,B)
  \tkzText[above](0,6.75){Desired Output}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with Peter, `Pgfplots` is the tool to use !!